# How to read Json using Gson in java

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson

I'm required to read a Json file, using the Gson library, in Java. First I don't understand what a Json file is, what I have is the following: (sorry for the lack of spaces, that's how it was pasted)

```
{
"initialStorage": [
{shoeType: "red-boots", amount: 10},
{shoeType: "green-flip-flops", amount: 7}
],
services: {
time: {
speed: 1000,
duration: 24
},
manager: {
discountSchedule: [
{shoeType: "red-boots", amount: 1, tick: 3},
{shoeType: "green-flip-flops", amount: 3, tick:10}
]
},
factories: 3,
sellers: 2,
customers: [
{
name: "Bruria",
wishList: ["green-flip-flops"],
purchaseSchedule: [
{shoeType: "red-boots", tick: 3}
]
},
{
name: "Shraga",
wishList: [],
purchaseSchedule: [
{shoeType: "green-flip-flops", tick: 12}
]
}
]
}
}
```

1. Do I just put it in java as.. String json = "-pasting it here-"? What is a "Json" file, is it some sort of a file I have to read as nameoffile.json?
2. How do I use Gson to read it? I didn't understand much from the youtube videos explaining it.

**The following link shows the given Json input in a more comfortable way:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0cTs.png

Comment: Jackson is a better choice from my view ...

Comment: Look at the GSON manuals, lots of examples.

Comment: "First I don't understand what a Json file is", then read about JSON! Then, read the GSON manual: https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md

Comment: GSON is Java library that can convert JSON to Java Object and vice versa. I parsed some JSON files a few weeks ago using GSON. First of all, I have question. What 'name` you want to get from that JSON file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**JSON** is short for JavaScript Object Notation, and is a way to store information in an organized, easy-to-access manner. In a nutshell, it gives us a human-readable collection of data that we can access in a really logical manner.

As a simple example, information about me might be written in JSON as follows:

```
{
    "age" : "24",
    "hometown" : "Missoula, MT",
    "gender" : "male"
}
```

To Read the `Json` file in java using `Gson` you need to use [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) lib.

Gson is a Java library that can be used to convert Java Objects into their JSON representation. It can also be used to convert a JSON string to an equivalent Java object. Gson can work with arbitrary Java objects including pre-existing objects that you do not have source-code of.

**Demo :** Read data from “file.json“, convert back to object and display it.

```
package com.mkyong.core;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class GsonExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Gson gson = new Gson();

    try {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
            new FileReader("c:\\file.json"));

        //convert the json string back to object
        DataObject obj = gson.fromJson(br, DataObject.class);

        System.out.println(obj);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }
}
```