# Getting Json data from (Local) android assets folder using retrofit

Tags: android, json, android-volley, retrofit, retrofit2

I am working on a project which required to access Json data from the local **android assets directory**. I can able to read json data from assets folder using **Volley Library** but i want to do the same thing using **Retrofit**. Below is my json file - `myfile.json` .

```
{
    "formules": [
    {
      "formule": "Linear Motion",
      "url": "<html><body>You scored <b>192</b> points. <img src=\"http://192.168.1.46/shanta_holdings/img/images/project-thumbs/Glasshouse-1.jpg\" alt=\"Smiley face\"/></body></html> ",
      "des":"Here is a description"
    },
    {
      "formule": "Constant Acceleration Motion",
      "url": "<html><body>You scored <b>192</b> points. <img src=\"http://192.168.1.46/shanta_holdings/img/images/project-thumbs/Glasshouse-1.jpg\" alt=\"Smiley face\"/></body></html> ",
      "des":"Here is a description"
    },
    {
      "formule": "Projectile Motion",
      "url": "<html><body>You scored <b>192</b> points. <img src=\"http://192.168.1.46/shanta_holdings/img/images/project-thumbs/Glasshouse-1.jpg\" alt=\"Smiley face\"/></body></html> ",
      "des":"Here is a description"
    },
    {
      "formule": "Force",
      "url": "<html><body>You scored <b>192</b> points. <img src=\"http://192.168.1.46/shanta_holdings/img/images/project-thumbs/Glasshouse-1.jpg\" alt=\"Smiley face\"/></body></html> ",
      "des":"Here is a description"
    },
    {
      "formule": "Work, Power, Energy",
      "url": "<html><body>You scored <b>192</b> points. <img src=\"http://192.168.1.46/shanta_holdings/img/images/project-thumbs/Glasshouse-1.jpg\" alt=\"Smiley face\"/></body></html> ",
      "des":"Here is a description"
    },
    {
      "formule": "Rotary Motion",
      "url": "<html><body>You scored <b>192</b> points. <img src=\"http://192.168.1.46/shanta_holdings/img/images/project-thumbs/Glasshouse-1.jpg\" alt=\"Smiley face\"/></body></html> ",
      "des":"Here is a description"
    },
    {
      "formule": "Harmonic Motion",
      "url": "<html><body>You scored <b>192</b> points. <img src=\"http://192.168.1.46/shanta_holdings/img/images/project-thumbs/Glasshouse-1.jpg\" alt=\"Smiley face\"/></body></html> ",
      "des":"Here is a description"
    },
    {
      "formule": "Gravity",
      "url": "<html><body>You scored <b>192</b> points. <img src=\"http://192.168.1.46/shanta_holdings/img/images/project-thumbs/Glasshouse-1.jpg\" alt=\"Smiley face\"/></body></html> ",
      "des":"Here is a description"
    },
    {
      "formule": "Lateral and Longitudinal Waves",
      "url": "<html><body>You scored <b>192</b> points. <img src=\"http://192.168.1.46/shanta_holdings/img/images/project-thumbs/Glasshouse-1.jpg\" alt=\"Smiley face\"/></body></html> ",
      "des":"Here is a description"
    },
    {
      "formule": "Sound Waves",
      "url": "<html><body>You scored <b>192</b> points. <img src=\"http://192.168.1.46/shanta_holdings/img/images/project-thumbs/Glasshouse-1.jpg\" alt=\"Smiley face\"/></body></html> ",
      "des":"Here is a description"
    },
    {
      "formule": "Electrostatics",
      "url": "<html><body>You scored <b>192</b> points. <img src=\"http://192.168.1.46/shanta_holdings/img/images/project-thumbs/Glasshouse-1.jpg\" alt=\"Smiley face\"/></body></html> ",
      "des":"Here is a description"
    },
    {
      "formule": "Direct Current",
      "url": "<html><body>You scored <b>192</b> points. <img src=\"http://192.168.1.46/shanta_holdings/img/images/project-thumbs/Glasshouse-1.jpg\" alt=\"Smiley face\"/></body></html> ",
      "des":"Here is a description"
    },
    {
      "formule": "Magnetic Field",
      "url": "https://www.google.com/",
      "des":"Here is a description"
    },
    {
      "formule": "Alternating Current",
      "url": "https://www.google.com/",
      "des":"Here is a description"
    },
    {
      "formule": "Thermodynamics",
      "url": "https://www.google.com/",
      "des":"Here is a description"
    },
    {
      "formule": "Hydrogen Atom",
      "url": "https://www.google.com/",
      "des":"Here is a description"
    },
    {
      "formule": "Optics",
      "url": "https://www.google.com/",
      "des":"Here is a description"
    },
    {
      "formule": "Modern Physics",
      "url": "https://www.google.com/",
      "des":"Here is a description"
    },
    {
      "formule": "Hydrostatics",
      "url": "https://www.google.com/",
      "des":"Here is a description"
    },
    {
      "formule": "Astronomy",
      "url": "https://www.google.com/",
      "des":"Here is a description"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have search over for a week but didn't get any proper solution for retrofit. I can able to read data from server using Retrofit. Is there any way to achieve the requirement using retrofit.

Comment: I think Volly and Retrofit used for rest API not for converting JSON from asset folder, Use GSON for parsing.

Comment: I have a question: **Why?** Why you want to use Volley and Retrofit where they shouldn't be used? Why you don't want to load the file directly?

Answer (score 0):

As Dheerubhai wrote Retrofit isn't used for parsing JSON objects. You can use GSON, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34532431/how-to-read-json-using-gson-in-java) to see how to make it work with Retrofit, you can see [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-retrofit-http-library/).

Comment: I am able to retrieve data from the server with retrofit . You may not clear about my question. I want to retrieve json data from a local file not from an url.

Comment: I see, but the first link includs an example of retriebveing data from locally stored JSON file.